# Could you clarify this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect):

> The **present perfect** in English is used chiefly for completed past
>    actions or events, when it is understood that it is the present result
>    of the events that is focused upon, rather than the moment of
>    completion.

I make an effort to explain it as following but not sure I am right.

*The present perfect in English is used to express an action or event that happened in the past & completed at the present time, but we don't care the time that action / event is completed.*

Comment: Exactly, the exact time of the experience isn't important.

Comment: There is one non-obvious part that you removed from the original: *chiefly*. This is important because the present perfect is not used exclusively for the actions or events stated as such in that sentence. For example, in *I've lived here for 10 years*, the speaker doesn't mean that their living here is completed and will not continue into the future.

Comment: @Ale Or even better, the exact point in time of experience is incompatible with the present perfect.

Comment: The quote from Wikipedia evokes the idea that present perfect has only one  use. But present perfect is used for several things.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is valid. I would only add one thing: the completion of the event ***should have a bearing on the present*** ... uh ... situation. Otherwise, the simple past would suffice.